# Removing certain amount of characters before index found in string

Tags: c#, string, replace, substring, indexof

I have a string which I need to remove certain characters from.

> string note = "TextEntry_Slide_7|Notepad one I am going to enter the text all over the place :)|250887|0^TextEntry_Slide_10|Notepad two: wrilun3q 4p9834m ggddi :(|996052|2^TextEntry_Slide_14||774159|4^TextEntry_Slide_16|tnoinrgb rt trn n|805585|5"

I want to remove the `^` characters and also the 9 characters behind the `^` character. So the string will look like:

> string note = "TextEntry_Slide_7|Notepad one I am going to enter the text all over the place :)TextEntry_Slide_10|Notepad two: wrilun3q 4p9834m ggddi :(TextEntry_Slide_14|TextEntry_Slide_16|tnoinrgb rt trn n|805585|5"

Also after that I need to remove the last 9 characters off the end of the string:

> string note = "TextEntry_Slide_7|Notepad one I am going to enter the text all over the place :)TextEntry_Slide_10|Notepad two: wrilun3q 4p9834m ggddi :(TextEntry_Slide_14|TextEntry_Slide_16|tnoinrgb rt trn n"

I've already removed a ton of other stuff that was originally in the string note but I am stumped on how to do the above.

I found the index of the `^` character like `note.IndexOf("^")` but I am unsure what to do next to remove the 9 characters before it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: please consider reformatting your question, it’s awful to read

Comment: I attempted to reformat, but your example strings are just too long to leave it legible without introducing extra characters. Please try simplifying your example to the minimum required to explain your request if you can. Also note the formatting help available.

Comment: @JamesBlackbjBlackburn: You can use four spaces at the start to get code formatting, that should help. Also note that your biggest problem is the length of the examples. A string that takes up 3 lines is hard to read.

Comment: Done my best to make it a bit more readable :)

Comment: Cheers Bali hopefully everyone will be able to read it now :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way is `Regex.Replace(note, ".{9,9}\\^", "");`

And the obvious way to remove the last 9 characters would be `note.Substring(0, note.length - 9);`

Comment: `@` at the start of the string allows you to use single `\\`.

Comment: It's not always desirable to use the @ though, since it disables all escape sequences. Here it's not much of an issue, but in general you want to save it for formats where you don't want any escape sequences (e.g. file paths). Using it in Regex definitions is not usually a good idea, since it will fail in the more general case.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, all you need is:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(note, @".{9}\^", string.Empty);
// remove last 9
output = output.Remove(output.Length - 9);
```

Comment: Marked as useful as also the answer

Answer (score 1):

First we strip of the carets and the nine preceding characters using a regular expression.

```
 var stepOne = Regex.Replace(input, @".{9}\^", String.Empty);
```

Then we just throw away the last nine characters.

```
 var stepTwo = stepOne.Remove(stepOne.Length - 9);
```

And you should probably add some error handling - for example if the string is shorter than nine characters after step one.

Comment: This works too, but had to accept Guvantes answer as he got there first. Cheers for the info man

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `.IndexOf("^")`, you can store that result/position into a temp-variable and then use a few `.Substring()` calls to rebuild your string.

Try something like:

```
int carotPos = note.IndexOf("^");
while (carotPos > -1) {
    if (carotPos <= 9) {
        note = note.Substring(carotPos);
    } else {
        note = note.Substring(0, (carotPos - 9)) + note.Substring(carotPos);
    }
    carotPos = note.IndexOf("^");
}
```

This will find the first `^` in the string and remove the leading 9 characters before it (including the `^`). Then, it will find the next `^` in the string and repeat until there are none remaining.

To then drop the last 9 characters from the string, you do one more `.Substring()`:

```
note = note.Substring(0, (note.Length - 9));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your language is, but in vb.net I used instr() function a lot for this. instr tells you at what position it finds the first match of a string inside another string, and if it didn't find a string it returns 0 or negative.

Next if you want to strip strings in vb.net you can easily do this with the mid() function in combination with len() function, len tells of the length together with instr you can calculate what you want from a string.

If you like to do this in C# check out this url: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=189